# Unable to see EC2 instance in amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a free account in amazon aws and created an EC2 instance using "Amazon Linux AMI". I could ssh to the instance and I installed NodeJS in it. I also purchased a domain name and configured it with an elastic IP to that instance.

Now when i login to the EC2 management console I couldn't see the instance. What might be reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which region did you create the instance?
Check the region at the top menu, to the right.

Comment: Yes I found it. it was in "US West (Oregon)", I'm new to this. How can find which reagin i created it. is there any shortcut for that?

Comment: I dont know if there's a easy way to find scattered resources on different regions, MAYBE the CLI could make the process more agile.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Happens all the time: "WHERE DID MY SERVERS GO??" - "Oh I'm in Ohio..."